# How to use nodejs with java in different layers of a micro service architecture?

Tags: java, node.js, spring, jakarta-ee, microservices

I am creating a web app that is designed for B2B so I took into consideration the fact that I will have a lot of load on my servers and requests . I like java as a backend and I used to use `spring mvc` and spring in `APIs` as my framework . and I know that best language or platform for high loads of requests is `nodejs`.

can I use `nodejs` as the web presentation layer to handle more requests and `java ee` with `spring boot` at the backend for heavy computation given that I am creating a `micro services` architecture ? or the `nodejs` will be useless at this point.

sorry if my question is wrong somehow but I must have a choice now before developing with my team, thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can, for example you could use Node as a Backend for Frontend, calling microservices in Java or anything else. But honestly, detailing such an architecture would be way too broad for Sack Overflow's Q&A.

Comment: @DidierL yes thats why i hesitated asking it on stackoverflow here , but i just wanted to know if it is applicable or no ? would adding nodejs at the first layer of the backend help me handling more requests till the java web micro service return the answer or no ?

Comment: This is way too broad as it depends on too many factors. You can do more or less the same things with both, and they both have a good performance. I doubt performance should be the main criteria when choosing between the two. It should probably be how easy it will be to develop, deploy and maintain your application instead.

Comment: @DidierL in case of development both are good to me and my team , ok tell me just the heading or titles of factors that i need to search for and i will search for them on the internet

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question and your comments, it seems to me that you want to use node.js as mid layer between your clients and your micro services...

For me, this seems pointless; because node.js will act a mere proxy, adding no value to your architecture...

The key point to bring node.js into the equation is to determine which of those microservices are IO-bound or
computational-bound. If they are IO-bound, they should be candidates to be written in node.js; otherwise, use javaee. I said "candidates" because depending of your business needs, you can use other means to speed up your application, like caches, etc.

I add some links that I found interesting about Java vs NodeJs, and microservices:

[performance-java-vs-node](https://www.tandemseven.com/blog/performance-java-vs-node/)

[Node.Js vs Java : Which is Faster for API's?](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/nodejs-vs-java-which-faster-apis-owen-rubel)

[microservices.io](https://microservices.io/)

Comment: i will have different micro micros services in my architecture , i though that node as a first layer in the architecture may help. i wanted to use java in the part of making computation and analysis on the data and then make it ready when called by node because node cant be good at computations .. so i mean that some services ar IO bound but they require some computations

Comment: say for example google, they are IO bound but they already sorted and managed their search to be queried when needed by user , at this point they used java or C++ for sorting and managing their data , and when it is needed they serve it ,    i have a similar case here , where i am IO bound but i want to make processing on the data so that it is ready by the services to be given to the user on request